# Best way to construct a string from components, iostream style

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stringstream

In many places in my code I need to construct understandable error messages, but creating string streams all the time is tedious, especially when you have to create a string in an constructor's initialisation list.  If this could be done with a simple function it would make the code significantly more readable.

Given one of many example use cases below, what would be an elegant way of implementing the below `createString` function?

```
struct Base {
    std::string msg;
    Base(const std::string& msg) : msg(msg) { }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    Derived(int value)
    // Parent constructor requires a string so we have to create it inline
    : Base(createString("This is class " << value))
    { }
};

int main(void)
{
    int i = 5; // some number obtained at runtime
    Derived d(i);
    std::cout << d.msg << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So far I have come up with this C++11 version, but it suffers from a few drawbacks (requires preprocessor macro, sometimes strings have to be enclosed in `std::string()`, etc.) so I'm wondering whether anyone has come up with a better alternative?

```
#include <sstream>
#define createString(a) \
    (static_cast<const std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << a).str())
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd pursue a [variadic template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) sort of solution.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Not a bad idea.  But would that provide much benefit over say a stringstream if the values are generated at runtime?  I can see a template working very well if all the values are known at compile-time.

Comment: The values need not be known at compile-time; only their *types*. Which you'll provide, because... you're invoking the thing with *something*.

Comment: This looks a bit like over-engineering to me. What's wrong with a simple `Base("This is class " + std::to_string(value))`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: That becomes extremely tedious when you are constructing a string from 20 or so different variables!  It would be over-engineering if it were just the one value, but I simplified it for the sake of an easy to understand example.  Besides, I'm not sure you can switch between hex and decimal, add leading zeroes, or use any of the other helpful iostream formatting options if you limit yourself to `std::to_string()`.

Comment: @Malvineous: That's true, but your question did not indicate (to me, at least) that you were dealing with such complex constructions. Still, striving for simplicity, I'd probably just use a static private member function to construct the string from a function-local string stream and call that function in the initializer list. Macros, variadic templates or casting... is all of this really worth the trouble? And will the code be easy to read (in contrast to just easy to write, which is less important)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a wrapper around `std::stringstream` and have it be implicitly convertible to `std::string`. It changes the syntax a little bit:

```
class WrapSStream
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  WrapSStream& operator<<(const T& val)
  {
    ss << val;
    return *this;
  }

  operator string(){return ss.str();}

private: 
  stringstream ss;
};

struct Base {
    string msg;
    Base(const string& msg) : msg(msg) { }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    Derived(int value)
    // Parent constructor requires a string so we have to create it inline
      : Base(WrapSStream() << "This is class " << value)
    { }
};

int main(void)
{
    int i = 5; // some number obtained at runtime
    Derived d(i);
    cout << d.msg << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs `This is class 5`.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b0f5735956a7468)